# brunch watch isn't compiling changed files

Tags: watch, brunch

I'm using brunch 1.7.14 and running brunch watch. The first change I make to a file is picked up and compiled correctly. All subsequent file changes are ignored so I need to stop and start every other time I make a file change.

I ran with `DEBUG=brunch:* ./node_modules/.bin/brunch watch` and on the second save, there is nothing printed at all.

I've tried removing node_modules and re-installing everything with no luck. I also tried re-cloning my git project in a completely new dir and running, but same problem there.

Anyone else had this problem or can suggest what may be wrong?

Comment: please post your package.json and config file

Comment: and are you using the `--server`flag? (`brunch watch --server`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this was a problem in chokidar which was fixed in this commit: https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/commit/9c1e4557eafce39ef044263e69c289d368e77a06

Updating the Brunch module and checking that chokidar version 0.8.4 is being used solved this for me.